# Android Path: Merge several paths and draw text on merged path

Tags: android, text, path, merge

In my application I have to merge several short paths to create a larger one. Example:

```
Path p1 = new Path();
Path p2 = new Path();
p1.moveTo(0,0); p1.lineTo(200,200);
p2.moveTo(200,200); p2.lineTo(400,0);

p1.addPath(p2); //merge

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawPath(p1, paint);
```

This works just fine and draws a neat V-shape to the canvas.

However if I want to use the merged path for text rendering (using `Canvas.drawTextOnPath()`), it only draws text along the first part of the path (i.e. the original `p1`). I'd like to use the entire path for text rendering, though. So is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out myself... The behavior described seems to be a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1342). I guess this is due to the fact that every path is internally seen as a separate "contour" which cannot be merged with another one.

However I was able to get the desired behavior with a simple "hack". This only works for line-based paths, though. Here's the code (minimal example), just if anyone's interested...

```
public class MyPath extends Path {

    private ArrayList<Float> points = new ArrayList<Float>();

    public void addPath(MyPath src) {
        this.points.addAll(src.getPoints());
        super.rewind();
        super.moveTo(this.points.get(0), this.points.get(1));
        for (int i = 2; i < this.points.size(); i += 2) {
            super.lineTo(this.points.get(i), this.points.get(i+1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void moveTo(float x, float y) {
        this.points.add(x);
        this.points.add(y);
        super.moveTo(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void lineTo(float x, float y) {
        this.points.add(x);
        this.points.add(y);
        super.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    public ArrayList<Float> getPoints() {
        return this.points;
    }

}
```

The usage of this is straightforward:

```
MyPath p1 = new MyPath();
MyPath p2 = new MyPath();
p1.moveTo(0,0); p1.lineTo(200,200);
p2.moveTo(200,200); p2.lineTo(400,0);

p1.addPath(p2); //merge

Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setTextSize(40);

canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawTextOnPath("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", p1, 0, 0, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use two paths? You can try using one like:

```
Path p1 = new Path();
p1.moveTo(0,0); p1.lineTo(200,200);
p1.lineTo(400,0);
```

and then use the the `Canvas.drawTextOnPath()` on `p1`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've already thought of this, but I'd have to rewrite the entire logic of my app in order to use only one path. Well, if nobody has a solution for several paths, I'll have to bite the bullet... ;)

Comment: I see. Maybe this can help: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/Drawtextalongwithpath.htm

Answer (score 0):

`Path.addPath()` still seems to be work-in-progress. You can avoid using it without extending `Path` by appending the multiple segments directly to the `Path` you will draw.

```
public void insertPart1( Path path ) {
    p1.moveTo(0,0); p1.lineTo(200,200);
}
public void insertPart2( Path path ) {
    p2.lineTo(200,200); p2.lineTo(400,0);
}

{
    Path p = new Path();
    insertPart1( p );
    insertPart2( p );

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawPath(p1, paint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't solve my problem; it's just a more detailed version of @0gravity's answer. You're assuming there's only one Path instance, however in my algorithm I have several instances (segments of a larger path) that have to be merged subsequently.